# Bigtable error with sbt assembly fat JAR (Neither Jetty ALPN nor OpenSSL are available)

Tags: java, scala, hbase, netty, google-cloud-bigtable

I would like to build a Restful API with akka-http able to retrieve data from Bigtable (HBase).

The Bigtable client API requires `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static` to connect. This works pretty well inside my Intellij IDE, but when I build a fat JAR with sbt-assembly, and then run the server, I get the following error:

```
2017-01-10 12:03:41 ERROR BigtableSession:129 - Neither Jetty ALPN nor OpenSSL are available. OpenSSL unavailability cause:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64, netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora, netty-tcnative]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at mycompany.algo.serving.model.algoServingModelLoaderTest$.loadLastModel(algoServingModelLoaderTest.scala:36)
        at mycompany.algo.serving.algoServingLauncherTest$$anonfun$4.apply(algoServingLauncherTest.scala:38)
        at mycompany.algo.serving.algoServingLauncherTest$$anonfun$4.apply(algoServingLauncherTest.scala:38)
        at mycompany.serving.MultiPredictorEbapServing$$anonfun$loadPredictors$1.apply(MultiPredictorEbapServing.scala:25)
        at mycompany.serving.MultiPredictorEbapServing$$anonfun$loadPredictors$1.apply(MultiPredictorEbapServing.scala:25)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at mycompany.serving.MultiPredictorEbapServing.loadPredictors(MultiPredictorEbapServing.scala:25)
        at mycompany.algo.serving.algoServingLauncherTest$.delayedEndpoint$mycompany$algo$serving$algoServingLauncherTest$1(algoServingLauncherTest.scala:38)
        at mycompany.algo.serving.algoServingLauncherTest$delayedInit$body.apply(algoServingLauncherTest.scala:11)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at mycompany.algo.serving.algoServingLauncherTest$.main(algoServingLauncherTest.scala:11)
        at mycompany.algo.serving.algoServingLauncherTest.main(algoServingLauncherTest.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalgotateException: Could not find an appropriate constructor for com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:88)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:72)
        at mycompany.algo.serving.model.algoServingModel$.<init>(algoServingModel.scala:25)
        at mycompany.algo.serving.model.algoServingModel$.<clinit>(algoServingModel.scala)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:85)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalgotateException: Neither Jetty ALPN nor OpenSSL via netty-tcnative were properly configured.
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.<init>(BigtableSession.java:279)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:104)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection.<init>(BigtableConnection.java:50)
        ... 26 more
```

What should I do ?

I am using Scala 2.11.8 and my sbt looks like:

```
dependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud" % "0.7.0",
  "com.google.cloud.bigtable" % "bigtable-hbase-1.2" % "0.9.4",
  "io.netty" % "netty-tcnative-boringssl-static" % "1.1.33.Fork19",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.2.1",
)
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT** Edited since I originally though it was caused by akka, but could reproduice it without Akka

**EDIT** My bad, the native libraries were evicted with my sbt assembly merge strategy

**EDIT** This works with Maven, the issue seems to be with sbt

**SOLUTION** This was caused by sbt-assembly default merge strategy.
I needed to add the below settings

```
val settings = Seq(
    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
        xs map {_.toLowerCase} match {
          case "native" :: xs =>
            MergeStrategy.singleOrError
          case _ => MergeStrategy.discard
        }
      case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
      case x => MergeStrategy.first
    }
)
```

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't need "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.2.1".  I'm also not sure about why you'd need "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud" % "0.7.0".  It's not a cloud bigtable requirement.

Comment: @Solomon "com.google.cloud" is needed for cloud storage, I forgot to remove it for the purpose of this post.
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" is needed for spark. There is no need for the purpose of this post

Comment: Is there a way to solve this exception with SBT ?

Comment: I solved the problem, but with different merge strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with SBT merge strategy, I used this strategy to solve the problem.

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "MANIFEST.MF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```