# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither Jetty ALPN nor OpenSSL via netty-tcnative were properly configured

Tags: scala, sbt, google-cloud-dataflow, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm doing a Bigtable + Dataflow project in Scala. Using sbt assembly to build a fat jar. It assembles fine, but I get the following run-time error as soon as I run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an appropriate constructor for com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:65)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:55)
    at com.snowplowanalytics.dataflow.streaming.storage.BigtableUtils$.setupBigtable(BigtableUtils.scala:60)
    at com.snowplowanalytics.dataflow.streaming.StreamingCounts$.setupDataflow(StreamingCounts.scala:71)
    at com.snowplowanalytics.dataflow.streaming.StreamingCounts$.execute(StreamingCounts.scala:139)
    at com.snowplowanalytics.dataflow.streaming.StreamingCountsApp$.main(StreamingCountsApp.scala:75)
    at com.snowplowanalytics.dataflow.streaming.StreamingCountsApp.main(StreamingCountsApp.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:62)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither Jetty ALPN nor OpenSSL via netty-tcnative were properly configured.
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.<init>(BigtableSession.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:92)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection.<init>(BigtableConnection.java:41)
    ... 11 more
```

I've read these questions and tried their suggestions but had no success.

- [How to solve "Neither Jetty ALPN nor OpenSSL via netty-tcnative were properly configured"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325120/how-to-solve-neither-jetty-alpn-nor-openssl-via-netty-tcnative-were-properly-co)
- [Bigtable error with sbt assembly fat JAR (Neither Jetty ALPN nor OpenSSL are available)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572790/bigtable-error-with-sbt-assembly-fat-jar-neither-jetty-alpn-nor-openssl-are-ava)

I'm using the following artifacts and versions (for google cloud related libs):

```
"com.google.cloud.dataflow" % "google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all" % "1.9.0"
"com.google.cloud.bigtable" % "bigtable-hbase-1.2" % "0.9.1"
```

Some other library I'm importing is dependent on google's protocol buffers lib, and that has originated a conflict, for which the merge strategy I used was discarding bigtable-protos-0.3.0.jar (in favor of grpc-core-proto-0.0.3.jar)

Comment: Have you looked at using shading in sbt? https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading I've encountered similar issues with protobuf conflicts that I solved in this way to build my fat jar

Comment: Did you add netty-tcnative-boringssl-static to your build?  Here's the maven configuration for thathttps://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-maven

Comment: Also, getting rid of bigtable-protos-0.3.0.jar should cause some other problems.  You need the bigtable protobuf objects in order to execute bigtable requests.  Here's an alternative Dataflow approach that includes a shaded version of the protobuf objects which will eliminate the conflict: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/dataflow-hbase.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"com.google.cloud.bigtable" % "bigtable-hbase-dataflow" % "0.9.5.1"` instead of `"com.google.cloud.bigtable" % "bigtable-hbase-1.2" % "0.9.1"`.  There's a lot of package renaming that had to be done to make hbase compatible with Dataflow.